# Texture Transparency in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, transparency, textures, glut

I am making a texture in my environment that excludes all white pixels. I read in a ppm file and the fourth value is always set to 0 if it is a white pixel. Everything seems to be in order, I have set up my view correctly and so forth. The texture image is visible with my current code, however the image as a whole is not fully opaque. It is highly see through. Is this a problem with how I am setting up my GL_Blend? Why is the entire texture not opaque as it should be only excluding the white pixels?

first three values are read in as rgb values and fourth value is not in file, it is selected depending on the total value of the three previous numbers from rgb. This texture is not loaded every time I render it is in a display list so only done once.

```
glPushMatrix();

    FILE *inFile3;
    char dump3[3];
    int max3, k3 = 0;

    inFile3 = fopen("tree.ppm", "r");
    int x3;
    int y3;

    fscanf(inFile3, "%s", dump3);
    fscanf(inFile3, "%d %d", &x3, &y3);


    fscanf(inFile3, "%d", &max3);
    int arraySize3 = y3*(4*x3);
    int pixel3, rgb = 0;
    GLubyte data3[arraySize3];

    for (int i = 0; i < x3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y3; j++) {
            fscanf(inFile3, "%d", &pixel3);
            data3[k3++] = pixel3;
            rgb += pixel3;

            fscanf(inFile3, "%d", &pixel3);
            data3[k3++] = pixel3;
            rgb += pixel3;

            fscanf(inFile3, "%d", &pixel3);
            data3[k3++] = pixel3;
            rgb += pixel3;

            data3[k3++] = ((rgb) > 760) ? 0 : 255;
            rgb = 0;
        }
    }


    fclose(inFile3);

    glGenTextures(1,&texture3);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture3);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);


    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D,4,x3,y3,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data3);


    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture3 );
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );

    glRotatef(180, 0, 0, 0);
    glTranslatef(0, -19, 0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2d(0,0); glVertex3f(30,0,10);
    glTexCoord2d(0,1); glVertex3f(30,20,10);
    glTexCoord2d(1,1); glVertex3f(30,20,-10);
    glTexCoord2d(1,0); glVertex3f(30,0,-10);

    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glPopMatrix();
```

Screen shots:
[image: Tree is not solid]

[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your texture and the end result?

Comment: No problem. I added screenshots. Tree is in the middle haha if it is hard to make out.

Comment: Just to be sure, before you specify your vertices, call `glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what @bernie pointed out about GluByte arrays and including glBegin/end, the problem was in..

> glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );

GL_MODULATE needed to be replaced with GL_REPLACE. This fixed the issue. Thanks for your guys' help.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the viewpoint really close to the tree, does it become opaque? Or does it if you disable mipmapping?

#### edit

By moving the eye closer to a tree, the level 0 mipmap (your original image) is used. To select a mipmap, OpenGL computes which level provides the best match between the size of its texels and the size of a pixel.

To disable mipmapping generation, you must use `glTexImage2D` to upload your texture instead of `gluBuild2DMipmaps`.

To disable usage of mipmaps, change the following line

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
```

to

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

You could also do as Jim Buck suggests and use

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
```

to force the highest mipmap level used to 0. The lowest being by default 0, this effectively disables mipmapping. By setting GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL and GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL to the same value, you will be able to see the content of that specific mipmap level.

All this is to confirm if it's a problem with the mipmaps.

Comment: Do you mean by moving the eye closer to the image? If so it has no effect. Why would disabling mipmapping do anything? I tried using glTexImage2D instead and it just made a blank square(transparent)

Comment: Try setting your max_level for mipmaps to zero and don't generate the mipmaps. This is just to confirm that it's not a bad mipmap.

Comment: i'm sorry I am a little lost to as in how I would do that.

Comment: `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0); glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);` - this will effectively not use mipmaps.

Comment: Heh, I didn't realize that @bernie added that particular stuff. :)

Comment: thanks for the edit, however it didn't work. I found the answer